# How to add all predefined languages into a ListPreference dynamically?

Tags: android, translation

I have ListPreference for selecting languages. The current trnalsations are defined in their own strings.xml as seen in the image. To fill the preference list i include the string-array elements inside the main strings.xml, making it a static configuration.

Question: Is there any way to make the Language ListPreference dynamic by iterating through all the strings.xml and extracting the Locale information from them some how on run time?

This is the current static setup:

values/strings/strings.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Preferences -->
<string name="pref_language">Language</string>
<string-array name="pref_language_list">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>Svenska</item>
    <item>Deutsch</item>
    <item>Français</item>
    <item>Português</item>
    <item>Español</item>
    <item>Pусский</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="pref_language_values">
    <item>en</item>
    <item>se</item>
    <item>de</item>
    <item>fr</item>
    <item>pt</item>
    <item>es</item>
    <item>ba</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

xml/pref_general.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <ListPreference
            android:entries="@array/pref_language_list"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_language_values"
            android:key="language"
            android:title="@string/pref_language"
            android:icon="@drawable/language"
            />
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

[image: Strings structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entries` and `entryValues` should work.

while I don't understand these useless string definitions & string assignments ...

add them directly into the arrays; into `values/arrays.xml`; with attribute `translatable="false"`.

and these language tags also don't match the resource file locations.

```
<resources>

    <string-array name="pref_language_list" translatable="false">
        <item>English</item>
        <item>Svenska</item>
        <item>Deutsch</item>
        <item>Français</item>
        <item>Português</item>
        <item>Español</item>
        <item>Pусский</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="pref_language_values" translatable="false">
        <item>en</item>
        <item>se-rSE</item>
        <item>de-rDE</item>
        <item>fr-rFR</item>
        <item>pt-rPT</item>
        <item>es-rES</item>
        <item>ba-rRU</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Sure, that modification makes sense. 

Though what I'm wondering is if you can populate a list with the locale definitions found in Strings (see image) at run time and not on compile time. 

The tags work, I've tested it.

Comment: @TiagoRedaelli don't think one can scan this directory; would only work with `raw` resources (which are not being processed when building the package). it is not, that one could not dynamically populate them, but one cannot scan the directory. when not in `strings.xml` it is a little easier to maintain, at least.